# how to form this REST request as a header, basic auth

Tags: rest, curl, basic-authentication

This is how I would do this http request with curl

`curl -v --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD`

how would I set this as a header in a different REST client?

I can create curl commands in php, but in other GUI based rest clients I am unsure what part of the rest call "basic authentication" really falls in, is it in the body? in a header structured a certain way? thanks for the insight

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Basic authentication](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#BasicAA) in HTTP is achieved by setting the `Authorization` header equal to `Basic token` where the token is equal the base64 of `username:password`. Follow the link for more details.